# New filter in JIRA

Tags: scrum, agile, jira, leadership, project-leader

How can I add a new filter that allows me to select tasks without a filled "estimate" field. I read about the ability to save search results as a new filter - but that doesn't work. I need to be able to filter by the "estimate" field, if it is not filled.

Comment: Hi - you're looking for a [JQL](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/jira-software/jql-the-most-flexible-way-to-search-jira-14) filter like [remainingEstimate is empty](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/JQL-to-find-tasks-in-progress-with-no-time-estimate/qaq-p/353674). With that said, I believe this question is way too specific on Jira to fix the pm.se guidelines. More details on [help].

Answer (score 1):

`project = myProject and estimate is EMPTY`

Where myProject is either the key prefix for your tickets (EX: JIRA or ABC etc) or myProject is the actual name of your project

And where estimate depends on what you use, story points, time logging, etc

We use time logging, so my JQL search would like this

```
project = "Legacy" and originalEstimate is EMPTY
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are estimating using story points, filter would be something like

```
project = PROJECT_NAME AND "Story Points" = 0 ORDER BY created DESC
```

You can omit Project = PROJECT_NAME as well. You can anyways replace story points field with whatever the estimate field you are using.

Comment: I'm 99% sure that SP = 0 <> SP = Empty.